# Python - Sometimes an appended row to a CSV file is added to the end of the previous row

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, append

Opening an exiting file and writing a dictionary to it sometimes appends the dictionary (being written as a row) to the end of the previous line.  How would I setup this code to always prevent that?  It seems to only happen when a previous code 'run' has crashed and I have restarted the code and it begins to write to a file from a previous run (which I want - just not added onto the end of a previous line).

```
        #Creating output dictwriter for results
        with open(csv, 'a', 0) as outputFile:
            fieldnames = csvCols
            successWriter = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            successWriter.writerow(out_dict)
        outputFile.close()
```

Would opening the file in 'ab' mode make a difference?

Comment: Are files from a "crash" missing a newline at the end of the last line? Is it as simple as checking the last line of a file for a newline character before you open the file for appending?

Comment: Note, you do not need the `outputFile.close()` line, as the `with` statement will automatically close the file for you.

Comment: Yes they are - I'm not sure how to do that.  And I also assumed that wouldn't be necessary since I was sure there could be some way to ensure an newline was always written.  Because, and this is where I am confused, the file is always closed when the script crashes - meaning, the crash never occurs in the bit of code above, but in some code that either precedes it or follows it - but the file is either not open or closed and already written to in those cases.

Comment: The point of using `with` is to ensure the file IS closed if the code crashes.

Comment: Great - I'll get rid of the .close() - is that causing the error, or are you just being tangentially helpful?

Comment: The later, it was just an observation. You are right though, you should use `ab` as the file mode if you are appending using `csv.DictWriter` (assuming you are using Python 2.x). Otherwise you will get an empty line per `writerow`.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually add "\n" to the file line so that it writes to the next line.

Comment: It happens automatically when writing to the file is proceeding normally. But if the script that calls the above code crashes, and I restart it, it appends the first newly written row to the last written row, but then proceeds normally, automatically creating new rows each time it is called. Your answer doesn't seem to address the fact that it takes care of new line characters by itself, most of the time.

Comment: Well the code is unlikely to be crashing if the file is adding items to the document. The document only updates when it hits .close()

Comment: No, it could crash in some part before this writing occurs.  What is being written is pulled form some web services - this one part is unlikely to crash or cause a crash, but sometimes the web service produces output that is junk and can cause a crash of the larger script that this section of code is in.  If that happens, and I restart the larger script, it begins to process the web service results again and begins to write to an already existing file, where it fails to write a new line the first time and then succeeds all other times.  Understand?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work fine in Python 2.x:

```
# Creating output dictwriter for results

with open(csv, 'ab') as outputFile:
    successWriter = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, fieldnames=csvCols)
    successWriter.writerow(out_dict)
```

The `with` statement will automatically close your file, even if there is a problem with your script. If you do not use the `ab` mode, it will result in an extra empty row per call of `writerow`.

If you are using Python 3.x, you would need the following:

```
# Creating output dictwriter for results

with open(csv, 'a', newline='') as outputFile:
    successWriter = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, fieldnames=csvCols)
    successWriter.writerow(out_dict)
```